# Hammer.js 2.0 and TUIO

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js

I have a rather large web app working with Hammer.js 1.1 and I wanted to move it to 2.0. This app does not work on a touch device: it works on regular Chrome to which we send touch data through TUIO and WebSockets. We use the magictouch library https://github.com/borismus/MagicTouch to trigger the touchstart, touchmove and touchend event on the DOM elements. This worked with Hammer.js 1.1. Hammer 2.0 does not seem to respond to any event triggered that way. Is fixing this a small thing or would it require a major fork of Hammer on our part?

Basically, in our use case, the browser has no idea of "tap" or "drag" event. We rely on Hammer to make those based on the basic TUIO events. A quick tour of Hammer 2.0's source code seems to indicate that 2.0 does not do that the way 1.1 did. Is that right?

EDIT: After this post, I looked at my code and at the Hammer code again. It seems Hammer 2 creates gesture detection just like Hammer 1, but something in my code intercepted the touch data before Hammer could get to it. The size of the rewrite this would have needed to fix was such that I decided to stick with Hammer 1 for now.